# Can FavoriteFiles of GExperts work with relative paths?

Tags: delphi, path, gexperts

We work usually on more than one version of the application, where each version is checked out in a different folder. The problem is when i try to open a file from the "Favorite files" of GExperts which i use it refers the absolute path that was set at the time this file was setas favorite. This causes lots of confusion sometimes, specially when the saved path exists, so one dont notice which file was opoened and keep working with the wrong file.

Is it possible to let GExperts work with relative paths, as the folder structure is actually allways the same, best would be if i could check the  in my repository and tell GExperts start from my root path.

Comment: What should the root path be - the current working directory, the directory of the current project or something else?

Comment: It can be anywhere, i have a Repo on svn and i check out two versions of the same application, so for example one is called C:\Version11 and the other on C:\Version12, the structure of the subdirectories is the same, so my problem is that eachtime i save a favorite file using GExperts let say its called File1 like: C:\Version11\subdir1\File1 i cant open it in the IDE when i work on Veriosn12 without correcting the path to Version12 instead of Version11. Hope this explains my problem

Comment: But from where should the expert know that it shall expand `..\subdir1\File1` relative to `C:\Version12` and **not** `C:\Version11`?

Comment: i thought to save the favoritefiles in my Repo, and let the GExperts start from there. is this possible?

Comment: I posted to the GExperts group: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/GExpertsDiscuss/message/3950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GExperts is open source. So feel free to implement yourself what you need and post it in the [GExperts discussion group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/GExpertsDiscuss/).
Read the [Developer FAQ](http://www.gexperts.org/devfaq.html) for a start. If you'll stumble on any concrete problems the discussion group would be a good place to find help.

**Edit**: After the OP's clarifications I could imagine one could add a menu item "Open custom repository" which would load his custom `C:\Version11\FavoriteFiles.xml` instead of the default one. Additionally one would need a new option `UseRelativePaths` per FavoriteFiles.xml file (default = False for backwards compatibility).

**Edit 2:** See [this message](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/GExpertsDiscuss/message/3969). There is now an option for custom collections and some support for relative file names in the FavFiles expert.

Comment: I can use a script which replaces foldernames in my FavoriteFiles.xml each time i get the Repository but this  not the answer im looking for, the question is about a configuration option to do that and not by programming it.

Comment: Re "not by programming it" - I believe there is no such option ATM, so somebody **has** to program it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.gexperts.org/faq.html#otherides it seems that GExperts stores its settings under the IDE's registry key (see "Where does GExperts store its settings and how to I move them to a new computer?"). So, I believe, you can try to edit those registry(before make a backup of your registry) with relative paths, and try in this way. This is what I can suggest at this moment. Let us know if it is working.

best regards,
Radu

Comment: Actually they write: "Data storage files other than configuration settings are stored in the GExperts storage directory you have defined in the GExperts Configuration dialog. This includes data storage for things like Favorite Files, Macro Templates, Code Proofreader, Clipboard History, Macro Library, and Code Librarian snippets."

Answer (score 0):

I say its not possible as GExperts write:

> Data storage files other than
>   configuration settings are stored in
>   the GExperts storage directory you
>   have defined in the GExperts
>   Configuration dialog. This includes
>   data storage for things like Favorite
>   Files, Macro Templates, Code
>   Proofreader, Clipboard History, Macro
>   Library, and Code Librarian snippets.

And there is no way to configure the way FavoriteFiles.xml is saved , so it seems to work only with absolute Paths.

Answer (score 0):

The recent (for a suitable meaning of recent) changes to the GExperts [Uses Clause Manager](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/gexperts-documentation/uses-clause-manager-expert/) allow you to open a unit from any of the lists, e.g. the list of units in the search path. And since the search path can be relative to the project file, this might solve the actual problem:

- Open the "Uses Clause Manager"
- Switch to the "Search Path" tab
- Type a part of the unit name and/or
- Select the unit you want to open (with the up/down arrow keys or the mouse)
- Click "Open Unit" or press Ctrl+O

(I'm aware that this is an old question, but the answer is still relevant I think.)